# What do you call the protruding square structures on the top of a tower?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here's an example:

[image: picture of bridge with a semicircular tower; the top of the tower has the tooth-like parts in question]

It's not a tower but the structure is exactly the same. I'm referring to the four 'tooth-like' juttings on top of the tower structure attached on the left of that bridge. What do you call them (I'm looking for a common word)?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Sorry. Fixed.

Comment: They could be *merlons.* Merlons need not be at the top of a tower, though. They occur through the "parapet," called the crenellation, in other places. They need not be square but can be triangular, and of other shapes. They may have "peepholes" in them as well!

Comment: it's TOTALLY UNCLEAR what you are asking about.

Comment: If it's unclear how come everyone has understood so far?

Comment: Nobody has understood it!  nobody was a clue what you're talking about.  Castellations, crenellations, merlons, parapets, are all totally different.  Do you mean "the thing you walk out on" or do you mean "one tooth of a castellation"?

Comment: OK updated. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: If you mean the "tooth" of castellations, sure, it's a "merlon" or I believe they just would say a "cop", "cops". They are for sitting your wine on top.

Comment: This question looks identical to this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38080/name-of-castle-part/38088#38088

Comment: @Joe Blow - To say nothing of rooftop hvac heat exchangers https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=rKK&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&channel=sb&biw=996&bih=537&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=rooftop+hvac+heat+exchanger&oq=rooftop+hvac+heat+exchanger&gs_l=img.3...8821.12633.0.13214.10.10.0.0.0.0.191.910.4j4.8.0....0...1c.1.54.img..10.0.0.6-VjDiSBoPo

Comment: Damn right, Wayfaring.

Comment: You should unaccept @phoog's answer. It is technically speaking "incorrect" although not far off.

Answer (score 2):

These are crenellations.  See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crenellation.

Comment: "The raised portions of a battlement ("A" in illustration) are called **merlons** " architecture . about . com  http://architecture.about.com/od/buildingparts/g/battlement.htm See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlon

Comment: Wiki uses the term *crenellation* to describe the "gaps" in the fortress wall. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlement.